# Correct syntax using JS 'onclick' functions inside PHP echo statements AND with embedded XML fetching

Tags: php, javascript, xml, syntax, echo

I am likely to get b'*ch slapped because I haven't searched the forum enough before posting, but I really think I searched all relevant posts already, many seem not specifically covering the question I have, the others fly right over my beginner's head ( as I am new to PHP & js ). That being said...

I have built a PHP code to fetch data from an XML file using the `$xml=simplexml_load_file();`

No worries there, however one of the needed data 'entries' or 'fields' needs to exist within an `onclick` and/or an `onmouseup` javascript function.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('prod_test_feed_sameday.xml');
        $max = 8;
        $i = 1;
foreach($xml->product as $feed){ 
if ($i <= $max){
echo "<table id='{$feed->position}' class='prod_container'>
        <td class='hidden_mask' id='{$feed->position}'>
        </td>
        <td class='hidden_image' id='{$feed->position}'><span style='background:url({$feed->prod_image_large}) no-repeat center;'/></span><div><a onmouseup='$('.hidden_image#{$feed->position}').slideToggle('slow');' onclick='$('.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}').hide();'><b>CLOSE</b></a></div>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td class='prod_image' id='{$feed->position}'>
        <span style='background:url({$feed->prod_image_small}) no-repeat center; background-size:contain;'/></span>         
        </td>
        <td rowspan='1' class='info_toggle' id='{$feed->position}'><a onmouseup='$('.hidden_image#{$feed->position}').slideToggle('slow');' onclick='$('.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}').show();><img src='images/zoom_02.png' title='See a larger image of these flowers' /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='prod_name' id='{$feed->position}'>{$feed->prod_name}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class='prod_price' id='{$feed->position}'><span id='{$feed->position}'>from: £{$feed->price}</span><a href='{$feed->prod_link}' target='_blank'><span class='buy_button'>&nbsp;Buy it now!&nbsp;</span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>";
            $i++;
        } 
      }  
?>
```

The data and the CSS all work perfectly.  There is a `href` link towards the end of the code, which also works perfectly.

I am racking my brain trying to find the error in my syntax within the `onlick` function.

I have tried all manners of backslashing, using trial and error, for exampel:

`onclick='$(\'.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}\').hide();'`   or
`onclick='\'$('.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}').hide();\''`    or
`onclick=\''$(\'.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}\').hide();\''`  or even
`onclick=\''$(\\'.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}\\').hide();\''`  <--Freddy Krugar 'slashing' example

At any rate I am at a loss.

Comment: Would it have anything to do with the "_" (underscores) in the HTML or XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with double quotes and escape them:

```
echo " ...
    onclick=\"$('.hidden_mask#{$feed->position}').hide();\"
...";
```

Or

```
echo " ...
    onclick='$(\".hidden_mask#{$feed->position}\").hide();'
...";
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/14Gyz)

This way you do the escaping in the PHP only, without needing the Freddy Krugar escaping for the DOM parser.

Comment: AWESOME- that was the key to it all.  The backslash with a quote rather than an apostrophe.     Cheers Fabrício!